# Automatically shift rows with same spatial coordinates into a different cluster

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cluster-computing

I have a dataframe `df`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
"latitude": [49.5659508, 49.568089, 49.5686342, 49.5687609, 49.5695834, 49.5706579, 49.5711228, 49.5716422, 49.5717749, 49.5619579, 49.5619579, 49.5628938, 49.5628938, 49.5630028, 49.5633175, 49.56397639999999, 49.566359, 49.56643220000001, 49.56643220000001, 49.5672061, 49.567729, 49.5677449, 49.5679685, 49.5679685, 49.5688543, 49.5690616, 49.5713705],
"longitude": [10.9873409, 10.9894035, 10.9896749, 10.9887881, 10.9851579, 10.9853273, 10.9912959, 10.9910182, 10.9867083, 10.9995758, 10.9995758, 11.000319, 11.000319, 10.9990996, 10.9993819, 11.004145, 11.0003023, 10.9999593, 10.9999593, 10.9935709, 11.0011213, 10.9954016, 10.9982288, 10.9982288, 10.9975928, 10.9931367, 10.9939141],
"cluster": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
"dup_location_count": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.head(11)

    latitude    longitude   cluster dup_location_count
0   49.565951   10.987341     0        0
1   49.568089   10.989403     0        0
2   49.568634   10.989675     0        0
3   49.568761   10.988788     0        0
4   49.569583   10.985158     0        0
5   49.570658   10.985327     0        0
6   49.571123   10.991296     0        0
7   49.571642   10.991018     0        0
8   49.571775   10.986708     0        0
9   49.561958   10.999576     1        2
10  49.561958   10.999576     1        2
```

The columns `latitude` and `longitude` represent the spatial coordinates of people. The column `cluster` represents the cluster. People who live at the same building or close to each other are usually in the same cluster. Each cluster has a cluster size of 9 people. The column `dup_location_count` represents the number of other people who share exactly the same coordinates.

I am looking for an automatic way to move people who share the same cluster, but have exactly the same coordinates, into a different cluster (see for example index 9 and 10). Preferably into a cluster which is "relatively close" to the original cluster. I have no exact definition of "relatively close" but the clusters with similar cluster numbers are closer to each other.

Note: make sure that even after shifting the people into different clusters, the cluster size stays the same (9).

Ideally I end up with a dataframe where each cluster contains people who live not at the same place and each cluster contains exactly 9 rows.

The original dataframe has 3k rows. Therefore I need some kind of algorithm to do the job.
Any ideas?

**Manual solution**

```
# sort values
df.sort_values(by=["cluster", "latitude", "longitude"], inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

# swap people
cluster_size = 9

temp_value = df.loc[2, "cluster"]
df.loc[2, "cluster"] = df.loc[2+cluster_size, "cluster"]
df.loc[2+cluster_size, "cluster"] = temp_value

temp_value = df.loc[4, "cluster"]
df.loc[4, "cluster"] = df.loc[4+cluster_size, "cluster"]
df.loc[4+cluster_size, "cluster"] = temp_value

temp_value = df.loc[5, "cluster"]
df.loc[5, "cluster"] = df.loc[5+2*cluster_size, "cluster"]
df.loc[5+2*cluster_size, "cluster"] = temp_value

temp_value = df.loc[18, "cluster"]
df.loc[18, "cluster"] = df.loc[18+cluster_size, "cluster"]
df.loc[18+cluster_size, "cluster"] = temp_value

temp_value = df.loc[20, "cluster"]
df.loc[20, "cluster"] = df.loc[20+cluster_size, "cluster"]
df.loc[20+cluster_size, "cluster"] = temp_value

# end of cluster therefore go backwards
df.sort_values(by=["cluster", "latitude", "longitude"], inplace=True)

shift_value = cluster_size - 1
temp_value = df.loc[30, "cluster"]
df.loc[30, "cluster"] = df.loc[30-shift_value, "cluster"]
df.loc[30-shift_value, "cluster"] = temp_value
```

This way I end up with the final result:

```
data = {
"latitude": [49.5633175, 49.5659508, 49.566359, 49.56643220000001, 49.56643221, 49.567729, 49.567729, 49.568089, 49.5687609, 49.5630028, 49.5659508, 49.56643220000001, 49.56643221, 49.5686342, 49.5695834, 49.5706579, 49.5716422, 49.5717749, 49.5619579, 49.5628938, 49.5633175, 49.56397639999999, 49.56397639999999, 49.566359, 49.56643221, 49.5677449, 49.5679685, 49.5619579, 49.5628938, 49.5630028, 49.5672061, 49.5679685, 49.5688543, 49.5690616, 49.5711228, 49.5713705], 
"longitude": [10.9993819, 10.9999593, 11.0003023, 10.9999593, 11.001122, 10.9982288, 11.0011213, 10.9894035, 10.9887881, 10.9873409, 10.9873409, 10.9999593, 11.001122, 10.9896749, 10.9851579, 10.9853273, 10.9910182, 10.9867083, 10.9995758, 11.000319, 11.0003023, 10.9999593, 11.004145, 10.9935709, 11.001122, 10.9954016, 10.9982288, 10.9995758, 11.000319, 10.9990996, 10.9935709, 10.9982288, 10.9975928, 10.9931367, 10.9912959, 10.9939141],
"cluster": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Hi, with the example you provided, could you show what the expected dataframe should look like (and why)?

Comment: Sure, just give me a second. I will add it to my original post. In words: I don't want any cluster have duplicates concerning ``latitude`` and ``longitude``. I want all people who share same cluster value to don't share same ``latitude`` and ``longitude``. Therefore I have to swap some rows into a different cluster.

Comment: I have added a manual solution. It is quite time-consuming to find the appropriate rows and move them by the right amount. Therefore I need a more automatic approach. Please take a look at each step I did.

Comment: In your manual solution, `df` has length 36, whereas its length is 27 in the example you provide? More importantly, in your solution, node 1 has size 10, not 9? Anyway, I suggest a different approach in my answer below. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to do it with Pandas [sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) and [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) methods:

```py
CLUSTER_SIZE = 9
df = df.drop(columns=["cluster", "dup_location_count"])
df_copy = df.copy(deep=True)
dfs = []
while True:
    for cluster_number in range(1 + df_copy.shape[0] // CLUSTER_SIZE):
        # Select a sample without duplicated coordinates
        while True:
            tmp = df_copy.sample(n=CLUSTER_SIZE, replace=False)
            if (
                tmp.drop_duplicates(subset=["latitude", "longitude"]).shape[0]
                == CLUSTER_SIZE
            ):
                break
        # Add new cluster number
        tmp["cluster"] = cluster_number
        dfs.append(tmp)
        # Remove sample from original dataframe
        df_copy = df_copy.drop(labels=tmp.index)
        if df_copy.shape[0] <= CLUSTER_SIZE:
            df_copy["cluster"] = cluster_number + 1
            dfs.append(df_copy)
            break
    # Check that no cluster contains duplicates
    for item in dfs:
        if item.duplicated(subset=["latitude", "longitude"]).sum():
            # Start again
            df_copy = df.copy(deep=True)
            dfs = []
            break
    else:  # if no duplicates found in any cluster, exit loop
        break


new_df = pd.concat(dfs).sort_values(
    by=["cluster", "latitude", "longitude"],
    ignore_index=True,
)
```

Then:

```py
print(new_df)
# Output

     latitude  longitude  cluster
0   49.562894  11.000319        0
1   49.563003  10.999100        0
2   49.566359  11.000302        0
3   49.568089  10.989403        0
4   49.568761  10.988788        0
5   49.569583  10.985158        0
6   49.571123  10.991296        0
7   49.571371  10.993914        0
8   49.571642  10.991018        0
9   49.561958  10.999576        1
10  49.562894  11.000319        1
11  49.563317  10.999382        1
12  49.565951  10.987341        1
13  49.566432  10.999959        1
14  49.567729  11.001121        1
15  49.567745  10.995402        1
16  49.567968  10.998229        1
17  49.569062  10.993137        1
18  49.561958  10.999576        2
19  49.563976  11.004145        2
20  49.566432  10.999959        2
21  49.567206  10.993571        2
22  49.567968  10.998229        2
23  49.568634  10.989675        2
24  49.568854  10.997593        2
25  49.570658  10.985327        2
26  49.571775  10.986708        2
```

Comment: Wow, I am very impressed by your solution. Thank you very much. The solutions looks correct. Let me make some tests and then I come back to you. Thank you so much!

Comment: May I ask an additional question to your great solution? In the current solution you move all people who share both same location (lat / long) and cluster, resulting in "clean" clusters without any duplications. What if I allow people to stay in the cluster as long we have not more then 2 duplicates per cluster? In other words: Do not shift all people into other cluster but only the people who have more then 2 duplicates per cluster.

Comment: Example: In the example above no teams have to be shifted according to this. But assuming index 24 would be `lat =49.5679684999999992` and `long=10.9982287999999997`, we would have 3 people in `cluster==2`, which means we have to shift one of them into a different cluster.

I guess it would be a small adjustment to your current solution, since the new approach would be subset of your current solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. In order to not confuse anyone, I have started a new post [here on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77319204/shift-rows-with-identical-spatial-coordinates-into-a-different-cluster-in-pandas). I have provided a minimal example and more explanation. The post is based on your work.

Comment: Thank you very much. In the linked stackoverflow post (see above), someone suggested to fix the problem by improving the way I apply the cluster algorithm in the first place. Well, not a bad idea. However, your approach is promising as well.

Comment: I took another look, here is the correct way, this time, to adjust my initial answer in order to have no more than 2 duplicates per cluster: replace `if item.duplicated(subset=["latitude", "longitude"]).sum():` with `if item.duplicated(subset=["latitude", "longitude"], keep=False).sum() > 2:`. Now, in your new post, you're asking for something much more complicated, I'm not sure how to tackle this, sorry. Cheers.