# Shift rows with identical spatial coordinates into a different cluster in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cluster-analysis

I have a pandas dataframe `df`. The columns `latitude` and `longitude` represent the spatial coordinates of people.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
"latitude": [49.5619579, 49.5619579, 49.56643220000001, 49.5719721, 49.5748542, 49.5757358, 49.5757358, 49.5757358, 49.57586389999999, 49.57182530000001, 49.5719721, 49.572026, 49.5727859, 49.5740071, 49.57500899999999, 49.5751017, 49.5751468, 49.5757358, 49.5659508, 49.56611359999999, 49.5680586, 49.568089, 49.5687609, 49.5699217, 49.572154, 49.5724688, 49.5733994, 49.5678048, 49.5702381, 49.5707702, 49.5710414, 49.5711228, 49.5713705, 49.5723685, 49.5725714, 49.5746149, 49.5631496, 49.5677449, 49.572268, 49.5724273, 49.5726773, 49.5739391, 49.5748542, 49.5758151, 49.57586389999999, 49.5729483, 49.57321150000001, 49.5733375, 49.5745175, 49.574758, 49.5748055, 49.5748103, 49.5751023, 49.57586389999999, 49.56643220000001, 49.5678048, 49.5679685, 49.568089, 49.57182530000001, 49.5719721, 49.5724688, 49.5740071, 49.5757358, 49.5748542, 49.5758151, 49.5758151, 49.5758151, 49.5758151, 49.5758151, 49.5758151, 49.5758151, 49.5758151, 49.5619579, 49.5628938, 49.5630028, 49.5633175, 49.56397639999999, 49.5642962, 49.56643220000001, 49.5679685, 49.570056, 49.5619579, 49.5724688, 49.5745175, 49.5748055, 49.5748055, 49.5748542, 49.5748542, 49.5751023, 49.5751023],
"longitude": [10.9995758, 10.9995758, 10.9999593, 10.9910787, 11.0172739, 10.9920322, 10.9920322, 10.9920322, 11.0244747, 10.9910398, 10.9910787, 10.9907713, 10.9885155, 10.9873742, 10.9861229, 10.9879312, 10.9872357, 10.9920322, 10.9873409, 10.9894231, 10.9882496, 10.9894035, 10.9887881, 10.984756, 10.9911384, 10.9850981, 10.9852771, 10.9954673, 10.9993329, 10.9965937, 10.9949475, 10.9912959, 10.9939141, 10.9916605, 10.9983124, 10.992722, 11.0056254, 10.9954016, 11.017472, 11.0180908, 11.0181911, 11.0175466, 11.0172739, 11.0249866, 11.0244747, 11.0200454, 11.019251, 11.0203055, 11.0183162, 11.0252416, 11.0260046, 11.0228523, 11.0243391, 11.0244747, 10.9999593, 10.9954673, 10.9982288, 10.9894035, 10.9910398, 10.9910787, 10.9850981, 10.9873742, 10.9920322, 11.0172739, 11.0249866, 11.0249866, 11.0249866, 11.0249866, 11.0249866, 11.0249866, 11.0249866, 11.0249866, 10.9995758, 11.000319, 10.9990996, 10.9993819, 11.004145, 11.0039476, 10.9999593, 10.9982288, 10.9993409, 10.9995758, 10.9850981, 11.0183162, 11.0260046, 11.0260046, 11.0172739, 11.0172739, 11.0243391, 11.0243391]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

In order to avoid clustering people who live at the same spatial coordinates I added additional columns to `df`:

```
# add a new feature
df['feature_dub'] = df.groupby(['latitude', 'longitude']).cumcount()

df['IsDuplicate'] = df.groupby(['latitude', 'longitude'])['feature_dub'].transform('count') > 1

df['IsDorm'] = df.groupby(['latitude', 'longitude'])['feature_dub'].transform('count') > 6
```

In the code above I assume that if `6` people have the exact spatial coordinates they live in a dorm.

Next step I do:

```
df['feature_dorm'] = 0

# Filter rows where 'IsDorm' is True
mask = df['IsDorm']

# Use cumcount to count non-zero occurrences of 'IsDorm' within each group of 'latitude' and 'longitude'
df.loc[mask, 'feature_dorm'] = df[mask].groupby(['latitude', 'longitude']).cumcount() + 1
```

Now I am ready to apply the cluster algorithm and hope that it does its job

```
from k_means_constrained import KMeansConstrained

coordinates = np.column_stack((df["latitude"], df["longitude"], df['feature_dub'], df['feature_dorm']))

# Define the number of clusters and the number of points per cluster
n_clusters = len(df) // 9
n_points_per_cluster = 9

# Perform k-means-constrained clustering
kmc = KMeansConstrained(n_clusters=n_clusters, size_min=n_points_per_cluster, size_max=n_points_per_cluster, random_state=42)
kmc.fit(coordinates)

# Get cluster assignments
df["cluster"] = kmc.labels_

# Print the clusters
for cluster_num in range(n_clusters):
    cluster_data = df[df["cluster"] == cluster_num][["latitude", "longitude", "feature_dub", "feature_dorm",]]
    print(f"Cluster {cluster_num + 1}:")
    print(cluster_data)
```

After applying a cluster algorithm called `KMeansConstrained` I get an additional column `cluster`. Each cluster contains 9 rows of people who live very close to each other:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
"latitude": [49.5619579, 49.5619579, 49.56643220000001, 49.5719721, 49.5748542, 49.5757358, 49.5757358, 49.5757358, 49.57586389999999, 49.57182530000001, 49.5719721, 49.572026, 49.5727859, 49.5740071, 49.57500899999999, 49.5751017, 49.5751468, 49.5757358, 49.5659508, 49.56611359999999, 49.5680586, 49.568089, 49.5687609, 49.5699217, 49.572154, 49.5724688, 49.5733994, 49.5678048, 49.5702381, 49.5707702, 49.5710414, 49.5711228, 49.5713705, 49.5723685, 49.5725714, 49.5746149, 49.5631496, 49.5677449, 49.572268, 49.5724273, 49.5726773, 49.5739391, 49.5748542, 49.5758151, 49.57586389999999, 49.5729483, 49.57321150000001, 49.5733375, 49.5745175, 49.574758, 49.5748055, 49.5748103, 49.5751023, 49.57586389999999, 49.56643220000001, 49.5678048, 49.5679685, 49.568089, 49.57182530000001, 49.5719721, 49.5724688, 49.5740071, 49.5757358, 49.5748542, 49.5758151, 49.5758151, 49.5758151, 49.5758151, 49.5758151, 49.5758151, 49.5758151, 49.5758151, 49.5619579, 49.5628938, 49.5630028, 49.5633175, 49.56397639999999, 49.5642962, 49.56643220000001, 49.5679685, 49.570056, 49.5619579, 49.5724688, 49.5745175, 49.5748055, 49.5748055, 49.5748542, 49.5748542, 49.5751023, 49.5751023],
"longitude": [10.9995758, 10.9995758, 10.9999593, 10.9910787, 11.0172739, 10.9920322, 10.9920322, 10.9920322, 11.0244747, 10.9910398, 10.9910787, 10.9907713, 10.9885155, 10.9873742, 10.9861229, 10.9879312, 10.9872357, 10.9920322, 10.9873409, 10.9894231, 10.9882496, 10.9894035, 10.9887881, 10.984756, 10.9911384, 10.9850981, 10.9852771, 10.9954673, 10.9993329, 10.9965937, 10.9949475, 10.9912959, 10.9939141, 10.9916605, 10.9983124, 10.992722, 11.0056254, 10.9954016, 11.017472, 11.0180908, 11.0181911, 11.0175466, 11.0172739, 11.0249866, 11.0244747, 11.0200454, 11.019251, 11.0203055, 11.0183162, 11.0252416, 11.0260046, 11.0228523, 11.0243391, 11.0244747, 10.9999593, 10.9954673, 10.9982288, 10.9894035, 10.9910398, 10.9910787, 10.9850981, 10.9873742, 10.9920322, 11.0172739, 11.0249866, 11.0249866, 11.0249866, 11.0249866, 11.0249866, 11.0249866, 11.0249866, 11.0249866, 10.9995758, 11.000319, 10.9990996, 10.9993819, 11.004145, 11.0039476, 10.9999593, 10.9982288, 10.9993409, 10.9995758, 10.9850981, 11.0183162, 11.0260046, 11.0260046, 11.0172739, 11.0172739, 11.0243391, 11.0243391],
"cluster": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Since the dataset contains many dorms or large buildings, it can happen that multiple people have the exact same latitude and longitude and therefore end up in the same cluster. Therefore we need some post-processing: Each time there are **more than 2 people** with same spatial coordinates I want to shift one (or more) of them into an adjacent cluster. Keep in mind, I don not want to shift them somewhere, but into a cluster which is next (or relatively close) to its original cluster.

First of all I try to find the critical parts:

```
duplicate_rows = df[df.duplicated(subset=["cluster", "latitude", "longitude"], keep=False)]
duplicate_indices = duplicate_rows.index.tolist()

# Group by specified columns and count occurrences
count_occurrences = df.iloc[duplicate_indices].groupby(['latitude', 'longitude', 'cluster']).size().reset_index(name='count')

print("Number of rows with identical values in specified columns:")
print(count_occurrences)
```

I get this:

```
Number of rows with identical values in specified columns:
           latitude                   longitude        cluster  count
0     49.5619579000000030      10.9995758000000006        0      2
1     49.5748054999999965      11.0260046000000003        9      2
2     49.5748541999999972      11.0172738999999993        9      2
3     49.5751022999999975      11.0243391000000006        9      2
4     49.5757357999999968      10.9920322000000006        0      3
5     49.5758150999999998      11.0249866000000001        7      8
```

Indices 0, 1, 2 and 3 are fine. Just each 2 people who share same spatial coordinates. I don't want to shift people from there, because value `2` (and less) in `count` works fine for me! In general, if possible, I want each person to **stay in its original cluster** and not move the person at all, because it is the optimal cluster for this person. However, both index 4 and 5 are problems. The goal is to shift some people of index 4 and 5 into adjacent clusters to minimize the number of value in `count`.

**What I have so far:**

Based on a [previous question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77160797/automatically-shift-rows-with-same-spatial-coordinates-into-a-different-cluster/77163618?noredirect=1#comment136281941_77163618) I have the following code which shifts **all** people with same spatial coordinates:

```
CLUSTER_SIZE = 9
df = df.drop(columns=["cluster"])
df_copy = df.copy(deep=True)
dfs = []
while True:
    for cluster_number in range(1 + df_copy.shape[0] // CLUSTER_SIZE):
        # Select a sample without duplicated coordinates
        while True:
            tmp = df_copy.sample(n=CLUSTER_SIZE, replace=False)
            if (
                tmp.drop_duplicates(subset=["latitude", "longitude"]).shape[0]
                == CLUSTER_SIZE
            ):
                break
        # Add new cluster number
        tmp["cluster"] = cluster_number
        dfs.append(tmp)
        # Remove sample from original dataframe
        df_copy = df_copy.drop(labels=tmp.index)
        if df_copy.shape[0] <= CLUSTER_SIZE:
            df_copy["cluster"] = cluster_number + 1
            dfs.append(df_copy)
            break
    # Check that no cluster contains duplicates
    for item in dfs:
        if item.duplicated(subset=["latitude", "longitude"]).sum():
            # Start again
            df_copy = df.copy(deep=True)
            dfs = []
            break
    else:  # if no duplicates found in any cluster, exit loop
        break


new_df = pd.concat(dfs).sort_values(
    by=["cluster", "latitude", "longitude"],
    ignore_index=True,
)
```

Comment: How does your initial clustering algorithm look like? Would it make sense to take that into account there directly instead of preprocessing?

Comment: I like your idea. Therefore I have added the steps of creating the clusters to my original post. I really hope it is still readable and clear. They way I did it, might not be the smartest. So please, If you have have a better way, let me know.

Comment: Here is a link to a [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nqixD8R86RkaO2lExvZOEmklUB2Cl0R3?usp=sharing)