# Automatic shifting of rows in dataframe based on column values

Tags: python, dataframe, algorithm, sorting

I have a question that has been bothering me for some time, also intellectually. I have already received an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77160797/automatically-shift-rows-with-same-spatial-coordinates-into-a-different-cluster) in the forum, but I have the impression that I do not yet have a solution here that I can apply to every data set without errors. I would therefore like to try again.

I have a dataframe `df`:

```
data = {
"latitude": [49.5659508, 49.568089, 49.5686342, 49.5687609, 49.5695834, 49.5706579, 49.5711228, 49.5716422, 49.5717749, 49.5619579, 49.5619579, 49.5628938, 49.5628938, 49.5630028, 49.5633175, 49.56397639999999, 49.566359, 49.56643220000001, 49.56643220000001, 49.5672061, 49.567729, 49.5677449, 49.5679685, 49.5679685, 49.5688543, 49.5690616, 49.5713705],
"longitude": [10.9873409, 10.9894035, 10.9896749, 10.9887881, 10.9851579, 10.9853273, 10.9912959, 10.9910182, 10.9867083, 10.9995758, 10.9995758, 11.000319, 11.000319, 10.9990996, 10.9993819, 11.004145, 11.0003023, 10.9999593, 10.9999593, 10.9935709, 11.0011213, 10.9954016, 10.9982288, 10.9982288, 10.9975928, 10.9931367, 10.9939141],
'Floor': [1,2,3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2,3, 6, 6, 2, 2, 3, 2 ,2 ,4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2 ],
"cluster": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],

}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


    latitude    longitude floor cluster
0   49.565951   10.987341   1   0
1   49.568089   10.989403   2   0
2   49.568634   10.989675   3   0
3   49.568761   10.988788   1   0
4   49.569583   10.985158   4   0
```

The columns `latitude` and `longitude` and "floor" represent the spatial coordinates of people. The column `cluster` represents the cluster. Each cluster has a cluster size of 9 people.

I am looking for an automatic way to move people who share the same cluster, but have exactly the same coordinates, into a different cluster (see figure). In best case scenario, the new cluster value is close to its original value. There is no definition of 'close', but since these clusters are made  by k-nearest neighbors, they reflect the proximity of each person to others. Thus, I aim to avoid moving individuals too far from their original clusters, although this is not a strict constraint.

Ideally I end up with a dataframe where each cluster contains people who have different spatial coordinats (`latitude`, `longitude` AND `floor`) and each cluster contains exactly 9 rows. If this is, for whatever reason, not possible, I want to end up with clusters  with a dataframe where each cluster contains people who have different spatial coordinats only based on `latitude` and `longitude`.

The original dataframe has 3k rows. Therefore I need some kind of algorithm to do the job. Any ideas?

[image]

**Note:**
Let's break the question down to the essentials. I am looking for an algorithm that finds cluster duplicates and then specifically changes the clusters of these duplicates so that all conditions are met. It is important that no new clusters are created. It is more about moving the clusters of the respective persons. The aim is therefore to move the relevant persons to another cluster in the cleverest possible way. Each cluster should still contain exactly 9 people!!!